Why do we use dative case in the sentence below
Er ist vor einer Stunde gegangen
With vor preposition, the following noun can be in accusative or dative case. However, movement (Bewegung) implies accusative case.
In this case, the verb gegangen indicates movement. Why do we use dative case with the noun?

Does this answer your question? Vor + Dative usage for action towards something

Someone told you a wrong rule. It's not about movement or not. But about direction vs non-direction. Check out this example:

Auf dem Marktplatz zeigt ein Wegweiser auf den Brunnen.

Nothing moves in this example. The verb is zeigen. Yet we have one auf with accusative case and one auf with dative case. That one adverbial auf+‹Akk› indicates the direction where the signpost points to. While the other adverbial auf+‹Dat› indicates a location where all this happens. At the market square.
And it's the same in your example.

Er ist vor einer Stunde gegangen.

That vor einer Stunde does not indicate a direction. Hence no accusative with vor. You have to take care about whether the noun argument of the preposition is really where the direction points to. Consider:

Der Stürmer schießt den Ball ins Tor. (The goal is the direction → in+‹Akk›)
Der Stürmer schießt den Ball am Tor vorbei. (The goal is not the direction. → an+‹Dat›)

And also be careful with phrasal verbs:

Sie wartet gerade auf den Bus.

That item auf den Bus isn't an adverbial at all but the prepositional object of the phrasal verb warten auf+‹Akk›. Hence the direction rule does not apply here.

"Someone told you the wrong rule." The thing is, many grammar sites and dictionaries for English speakers give some version of this rule. For example Wiktionary uses the label "[with dative (indicating location) or accusative (indicating movement)]".  I can see why; the actual usage is somewhat nuanced, and it's easier to give a shortened, oversimplified version than to actually explain it correctly. But incorrect information is worse than no information. Ironically, German language dictionaries explain it more accurately when German speakers presumably don't need to be told the difference.

First, the distinction between Dative and Accusative does not depend on movement, it depends on place (Dative) or direction (Accusative).
In your example, "vor einer Stunde" (one hour ago) is about time, not place and not direction.
